# check if any column in JSON object is undefined/null/empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new, but did run a search that yielded no results on this topic. Is there any way to check a JSON object for blanks?

Like if(json[randomInt()].hasBlanks) or something to that effect? Or do I have to ask for each column manually?

Comment: JSON cannot have undefined or empty values, so the only thing to check for would be `null`

Answer (score 0):

There are no columns in JSON. It's a document format not a table format. That means that every entry ("row") in an array can have any fields. Field names in one array entry can be completely different from the previous or any other. So in that sense, no, such a function does not exist. You would have to write it yourself.

Comment: I appreciate clearing that up, JSON makes a bit more sense to me now.